# Options for removing failed prints

Tags: bed, m3d

So basically I've been having a problem with my Micro+.
It will not level / calibrate itself and I can't fix it. The reason I'm here is that I've been using Cura, and somehow it destroyed my bed. (See image)

[image: print bed for Micro +]

I would like to know how to get it off, as I tried freezing, scraping and sandpaper

---

To clarify some things:

- The material is PLA,
- bed is made of plastic.

My build plate surface got destroyed after trying to use Cura, which sliced wrong and engraved the print into my bed.

Comment: Can you give us a little more on "somehow it destroyed my bed"?

Comment: I was using cura and my slicer settings were way off. It basically engraved the print into the bed.

Comment: What material was that? You might have a chance if it was ABS. If it PLA or PETG, you're probably SOL...

Comment: To be honest, you destroyed the surface yourself (please, this is not meant as an offending comment). Any slicer will instruct what you have set it to do, so, you either have set incorrect settings in the slicer, or you have not properly zeroed the Z-axis, or you have a mechanical issue with the Z-axis. This cannot solely be a slicer problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a time, it was the same with me, I sanded the surface well and continued for a while without any problems. The only problem was the sand pattern that was always visible in the bottom of models and finally I upgraded the bed to PEI sheet.

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried [every](/q/11707/) [trick](/q/7592/) to remove the print, you probably need to [replace](/q/7960/) the build surface. If the PLA is "engraved" into the build surface, your surface is damaged anyways, just replace the surface, or remove the top surface and buy a sheet of glass, preferably borosilicate.

Comment: Thanks 0scar but the issue has been resolved. Needed some intense scraping and sanding, but I managed to clean the bed and applied some masking tape to it so this wont happen in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Print a filled square 2 layers thick over the whole surface of the bed and then peel off when it's still warm, so that it may take away also the previous deposits.

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting it in the oven at 100 °C and then peeling it off. At that temperature it's soft as cheese.

Comment: My bed would also be as soft as cheese. I want to upgrade to a glass sheet, but M3D has these little clips for the premade bed that would block it. Only option is to break off those clips

Comment: Too bad man. :( I also had a plastic sheet as print bed before and occasionally have PLA stuck to it. (Bronzefil sticks like crazy!) I switched to a magnetic bed that you can bend. That has the best of 2 worlds: perfect stickability and easy removability. I love it and it's worth the price!