# What do I do when my magnetic bed looks like this after a failed print

Tags: bed-leveling, print-failure

I'm having a lot of issues leveling my printer and one failed print came out like this. Is there something wrong with the surface that I need a new bed? This happens to me quite often and I literally can't get it off.

[image: Magnetic bed with filament still stuck to bed]

Comment: What type of filament are you using?

Comment: PLA, don't know the specifics but its silk gold

Comment: Interesting, I had heard that some filaments adhere **really** well to PEI sheets, but not PLA. Maybe the nozzle is too close to the bed and therefore sticking too well.

Comment: Are you asking what is **causing** the filament to stick? or are you asking if the adhesion is not working properly and therefore need to get a new magnetic bed?

Comment: yes I'm wondering if I need to get a new bed if it gets out of hand

Comment: I have edited your question a little bit for clarification. If it is not to your liking, feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: @desperrrr: Even if you did, it would just be a new bed surface you'd need, not an entire new bed. This is a good spare/consumable item to have on hand in advance in case you mess yours up worse than you did.

Comment: @agarza: That's not PEI. It's textured "buildtak clone".

Comment: Have you seen [Options for removing failed prints](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/15891/)? This question is pretty similar with regards to removing the print residu. If the sheet is too much damaged, you should replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Print the print once more. the first few layers will adhere to the excess material and you can then peel it all off.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. This sounds more like a comment than an answer. Also, when you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: This is the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

If it's flat so you cannot scrape it off you can just print over it. No need for a new bed.

Check your levelling first because if it's sinking into the bed then the nozzle is far too low and you can end up with a scenario where it rips the bed material when you remove a print.